# Locate tab element within tab (parent and child tab)

Tags: jasmine, protractor

In my page, there is 2 mat-tab element. One is for parent, and one is for child.

I am trying to click the tab in my child tab, but when protractor runs, it failed because it always goes to the parent first thus failed to locate the child tab. Both having same css aside from the label.

This is how i done it previously. Previously there is no parent tab, thus it is working:

```
this.addressTab=element(by.css("div[class='mat-tab-labels']")).element(by.css("div[aria-posinset='2']")).click();
```

I cannot use id, mat-tab-label or mat-tab-content to locate the css because the test case is repetitive and the index and id will be changing each time form is saved.

This is parent tab:

```
<mat-tab-header class="mat-tab-header" ng-reflect-disable-ripple="false" ng-reflect-selected-index="1">
   <div aria-hidden="true" class="mat-tab-header-pagination mat-tab-header-pagination-before mat-elevation-z4 mat-ripple mat-tab-header-pagination-disabled" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="true">
      <div class="mat-tab-header-pagination-chevron"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="mat-tab-label-container">
      <div class="mat-tab-list" role="tablist" style="transform: translateX(0px);">
         <div class="mat-tab-labels">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
               }-->
            <div cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="mat-tab-label mat-ripple ng-star-inserted" mat-ripple="" mattablabelwrapper="" role="tab" ng-reflect-disabled="false" id="mat-tab-label-2-0" tabindex="-1" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="2" aria-controls="mat-tab-content-2-0" aria-selected="false" aria-disabled="false">
               <div class="mat-tab-label-content">
                  <!--bindings={
                     "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object]"
                     }--><!--bindings={
                     "ng-reflect-portal": "[object Object]"
                     }--> Overview <!----><!--bindings={
                     "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
                     }-->
               </div>
            </div>
```

This is the child tab html:

```
<mat-tab-header class="mat-tab-header" ng-reflect-disable-ripple="false" ng-reflect-selected-index="0">
   <div aria-hidden="true" class="mat-tab-header-pagination mat-tab-header-pagination-before mat-elevation-z4 mat-ripple mat-tab-header-pagination-disabled" mat-ripple="" ng-reflect-disabled="true">
      <div class="mat-tab-header-pagination-chevron"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="mat-tab-label-container">
      <div class="mat-tab-list" role="tablist" style="transform: translateX(0px);">
         <div class="mat-tab-labels">
            <!--bindings={
               "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
               }-->
            <div cdkmonitorelementfocus="" class="mat-tab-label mat-ripple mat-tab-label-active ng-star-inserted" mat-ripple="" mattablabelwrapper="" role="tab" ng-reflect-disabled="false" id="mat-tab-label-3-0" tabindex="0" aria-posinset="1" aria-setsize="4" aria-controls="mat-tab-content-3-0" aria-selected="true" aria-disabled="false">
               <div class="mat-tab-label-content">
                  <!--bindings={
                     "ng-reflect-ng-if": "[object Object]"
                     }--><!--bindings={
                     "ng-reflect-portal": "[object Object]"
                     }--> Patient information <!----><!--bindings={
                     "ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
                     }-->
               </div>
            </div>
```

How can i go the child tab or what selector can I use in this case to get to the child tab?

Or is there a way to insert name/label inside the tab html? I asked my developer but he has no idea if that can be done as it is automatically generated by angular component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to locate the element. I am using 3 chain locators instead of 2:

```
element(by.css("mat-card[class='mat-card ng-star-inserted']")).
element(by.css("div[class='mat-tab-labels']")).
element(by.css("div[aria-posinset='2']"))
```